# Function relation notation with the cartesian product.

Tags: logic, notation

This excerpt comes from one of my lectures:

[image: Excerpt]

I'm assuming that the sets A and B are example sets? If so, does that mean that if I was working with the sets X and Z I could rewrite the above as:

> P₁: X x Z ↦ X; (x, z) ↦ x

What does the lowercase x and z represent? Elements of the sets X and Z?

Answer (score 0):

It means that $p_1$ is a function from the set $A \times B$ to $A$, and that it is defined by "the pair $(a, b) \in A \times B$ is sent to $a$".

If you were working with $X$ and $Z$, then you could write $p_1: X \times Z \to X$ by $(a,b) \to a$, or by $(x, z) \to z$, or by $(\alpha, \aleph) \mapsto \alpha$, or whatever you wanted really.

It's the same notation as, for example, $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; x \mapsto x+7$$

Comment: Thanks. So should I use (a, b) or (x, z)? Or does it really not matter like you said?

Comment: Whichever. It's basically the same question as asking whether you should use $x$ or $z$ as your variable; the answer is that it doesn't matter, although the reader would be a little bit confused if you used $y \in X, x \in Y$.

Comment: So I should use (a, b) for clarity?

Comment: Probably easiest, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.